# Why is it impossible for the mapping $x\mapsto 1/x$ to be a polynomial in an infinite field?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Let $K$ be an infinite field and consider the map $x\mapsto 1/x$ on $K^\times$. I want to show it is not possible for this map to be a polynomial in the input $x$.

My idea for a proof goes like this: assume for contradiction that the map is a polynomial. Then there is some polynomial $p$ such that
$$
1/x = p(x) 
$$
for all $x\in K^\times$. My plan then would be to get $1=xp(x)$ and then make some argument about having infinitely many linear equations... but I'm not super happy with justifying the details of that. Would people agree this is how one should proceed? Or is there a better way?

Comment: If $x p(x) = 1$, then $x = 0$ implies $0 = 1$.

Comment: @user771918: I think we need to say a bit more than that. At first sight, we only have $1=xp(x)$ for $x\in K^\times$. So there would need to be an argument that this implies that the equation also holds for $x=0$. Since this is not the case for $K=\mathbb F_3$, the fact that $K$ is an infinite field needs to enter the picture somehow.

Comment: @user771918 $x=0$ is excluded from from the domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial $xp(x)-1$ has at most $\deg p+1$ roots, so it can’t have all the infinitely many elements of $K^\times$ as roots.

Answer (score 2):

From Jose, $xp(x)$ would have positive degree and thus $x(p(x))-1$ would be a non-constant polynomial with infinitely many roots which is impossible.